# Is java.net.CookieManager good enough?

Tags: java, cookies

I'm building a JavaFX application and there seem to be two implementations of CookieHandler:

- java.net.CookieManager
- com.sun.webkit.network.CookieManager

The application, by default, seems to be using the latter, but I need a feature of the former (`getCookieStorage().getCookies()`). Is java.net.CookieManager good enough? I read somewhere but now I can't find it that someone from Oracle recommended staying away from that because it wasn't properly RFC compliant like the webkit one is.

Is that true?

Comment: According to their sources, the former conforms to `RFC 2965 section 3.3` while the latter announces to be `An RFC 6265-compliant cookie handler`.

Comment: I just did some experiments with both cookie handler's and java.net's one doesn't seem to work at all when trying to log in to New Relic.

Comment: Maybe they're not RFC 2965 compliant? A lot of documentation seems to address the customizability of the `java.net` one, but I've never done anything with either, so I don't have any better information about their differences and pros/cons.